# How do I change the frame rate when working in 2d animation?

Tags: animation, 2d, frame-rate

How do I change the frame rate when working in 2d animation?

I have a feeling there’s a simple solution to my problem.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "change the fps 2d"?

Comment: change the frame rate in the 2d workspace... sorry i wasn’t clear! new to Blender

Answer (score 2):

The framerate **for all projects** in blender is set in the Properties window >  Output > Dimensions > Frame Rate

[image]